# Cannot tell whether Node 16 NPM 8 invocation is succeeding or failing

Tags: node.js, npm, babylonjs

New to Node and NPM and trying to play around with [babylon.js](https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js). I installed NVM and switched to Node 16 using `nvm use 16`. Then I upgraded NPM via `npm install -g npm@8.7.0`. So far so good.

Then, just like the docs say, I attempt to install the Babylon modules:

```
npm install babylonjs --save
```

However the output for this command is:

```
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0: 3.x is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.

added 952 packages, removed 4 packages, changed 31 packages, and audited 1162 packages in 34s

87 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

21 vulnerabilities (8 moderate, 12 high, 1 critical)

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

I would expect to see a friendly message that says something like:

> "*The babylonjs modules have been successfully installed*"

That's the type of message you'd get using a mature build system such as Maven or Gradle. Or, if it failed, I'd expect to see *something* like:

> "*Failure: NPM failed to install the modules because of X*"

But **instead** I see a bunch of unsettling versioning/security (vulnerabilities detected) warnings and a message that reads:

```
To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

This leaves me with several unsettling feelings. The main question here is: **Did the command succeed?** Are the babylonjs modules installed? Did they install correctly? How can I tell? My current directory is still empty...

However, as an aside: do I need to be concerned about all of these warnings? Did they prevent the babylonjs modules from installing properly?

With Maven or Gradle, it will tell you (clear as day) whether your CLI invocation failed or succeeded, but this output is neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, the installation did occur and from the looks of it, it was successful.

Everything else you are seeing is as a result of the interconnectedness and vastness of the npm ecosystem. The warnings at the top refer to nested dependencies of `babylon.js`, which may have been deprecated in favour of other modules. There is nothing you can do about this.

However, if you are feeling very keen and you know the authors whose libraries depend on these deprecated ones, you can ask them (nicely) to release new versions of their package without those deprecated packages; Then ask the authors `babylon.js` (once again, nicely) to upgrade their dependencies to the version released by those authors.

---

#### tl;dr

The warnings about vulnerabilities, followed by the command (`npm audit fix`) to fix them is probably the most you can do just to be safe. Run the command and continue your work.

Comment: Thanks (+1), is there a command I could run (if this happens in the future) to verify the modules installed successfully? Or a place on my file system where I could look? I'm on a Mac if it makes a difference.

Comment: And is there a way to generate a "dependency tree" or graph so I could see which nested dependencies are using these deprecated packages?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup Try `npm ls` to view installed packages (you can also check the `node_modules` folder which is created when you install packages). To check if packages installed correctly, run `npm ci` which basically compares packages listed in `package.json` with the ones add to `package.lock.json`

Comment: Interesting. When I run `npm ci` it gives me the same output as the WARNs above. I run this from `~/workspace/babylon-test` (my test project). But `~/workspace/babylon-test` is empty; there is no `package-lock.json` or `package.json` files in it at all (nor anything else). However there are those files located in my homedir (`~`) and they were created today. Does that sound right to you? Thanks again for all the help thus far.